# Modelio state machine : using operations

Tags: state, modelio

I am new to Modelio (I am using Modelio 3.3) and I am trying to describe the behaviour of an object using a state machine. The problem I am facing is that when I try to use an operation as an action for an internal transition, I do not know how to specify its arguments.
The operation is move(p1 in: string) and the value of the "Expression of the action" field of the internal transition is move(string) but I do not see how to give a specific value to p1.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can not specify a value at this point.
This is mainly due to the fact that you modelling a general behavior not a concrete one. 
In UML, at the "type level", you do not specify values except default values. Concrete or specific value like operation parameter value can only be specified at the Object/instance level.